# how to hide/close a qTip2 without selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I'm dynamically generating a qTip2 tooltip and I want to close/hide it from a javascript function, how can i do that? any idea?

This is how I generate the qTip2:

```
    var ToolqTip = $('<div />').qtip({
        content: {
            text: this.html,
            title: {
                text: currentItem["Item"].name,
                button: true
            }
        },
        position: {
            at: "right center",
            my: "left center"
            //target: $("#location_header")
            ,adjust: {
                method: "flip shift",
                x: 15, y: -25
            }
            ,target: pos
            //,viewport: $('#map_canvas')
            //,container: $('#map_canvas') // this one prevents overlaping
        },
        show: {
            ready: true,
            event: false,
            solo: true
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools'
        }
        /*,
                    hide: {
                        event: 'mouseleave unfocus'
                    }*/
    });
```

I want to close it from a call from this function

```
function pleaseClose(){
    $().qtip('hide'); // NOT WORKING :(
}
```

any idea? Please!

Answer (score 1):

```
function pleaseClose(){
    ToolqTip.hide()
}
```

should do it...

Comment: Your answer didn't work :(. At the end I decided to propagate the action on all the divs with: $("div").qtip('hide');

Comment: instead of doing it on all divs, you can do ToolqTip.qtip('hide'); which targets only the existing object. this is more efficient than targeting all divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can you an API call to toggle visibility

```
 function pleaseClose(){
   var api = $('yourSelector').qtip();
   api.toggle(false); //hide
 };
```

To show:

```
 api.toggle(true); //show
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pleaseClose(){
    $(ToolqTip).qtip('toggle', 'false');
}
```